# Workflow for working with data sent from javascript script to php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I have a Javascript file which reads in some data from a text file and prints it into html tables.
I do also send the data to PHP using Ajax and then from there I would like to put it into proper form and then send it to my MySQL database.

What I found difficult is working with the PHP-code when it is in another file that is called from the Javascript file. I echo some back to view it in the console, but for example if I make some errors then the error messages have a less ideal form coming into the console:

```
br />
<font size='1'><table class='xdebug-error xe-warning' dir='ltr' border='1' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='1'>
<tr><th align='left' bgcolor='#f57900' colspan="5"><span style='background-color: #cc0000; color: #fce94f; font-size: x-large;'>( ! )</span> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\wamp\www\Load data from txt file using Jquery\myscript.php on line <i>9</i></th></tr>
<tr><th align='left' bgcolor='#e9b96e' colspan='5'>Call Stack</th></tr>
```

From my Javascript file:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "myscript.php",
  data: {sentData : myJSONstring}, 
  //cache: false,

  success: function(data){
     console.log(data);
  }
});
```

From my myscript.php file (currently just grabbing the incoming data and echoing it back):

```
<?php
    $data = $_POST['sentData'];
    echo $data;
?>
```

What better ways are there for me to work with this? My current approach looks (at least to my hobby-programming eyes) like writing a novel standing 5 meters away from the computer and using a long stick to hit on the tangents of the keyboard with.

I feel like I really don't see what is going on in the PHP script. Normally I've sent data back and forth between a PHP-file and MySQL database and it's been easier as I've echoed everything back into the browser window, but now the PHP-file is in some kind of middle-ground between the JS-file and the MySQL database and not being a very good PHP-programmer the process of writing and debugging the PHP-file is a bit challenging to me.

Comment: It's hard to offer advice not knowing what you're trying to do with that data, but if it's JSON, the first thing I'd do is [`json_decode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) it so I have an array to work with.

Comment: I'd like to pick out some data from the incoming data to place it in some mysql columns.

I was actually trying to do that but that was where my difficulties began when the result in the console was:
<pre class='xdebug-var-dump' dir='ltr'>
<b>array</b> <i>(size=197)</i>
  0 <font color='#888a85'>=&gt;</font> 
    <b>object</b>(<i>stdClass</i>)[<i>1</i>]
      <i>public</i> 'Name' <font color='#888a85'>=&gt;</font> <small>string</small> <font color='#cc0000'>'Amravati Thermal Power Station'</font> <i>(length=30)</i> ....and I simply didn't know where to go with this as it's not an error

Comment: This is what is coming back from the none json decoded version:
[{"Name":"Amravati Thermal Power Station","Country":" India","Geographic position":"21°01'21?N 77°49'25?E","Power":2700},{"Name":"Arnot Power Station","Country":" South Africa","Geographic position":"25°56'38?S 29°47'22?E","Power":2352},{"Name":"Banqiao Power Station","Country":" China","Geographic position":"31°56'52?N 118°37'49?E","Power":2070}...